# Finding the gain difference for a ultrasonic assembly

Tags: ultrasound, decibel, tuning

I am tuning an ultrasonic assembly for a welding application and tuned the system to operate at 41kHz according to the oscilloscope. The transducer operates at 40kHz, when calculating the gain with the peak to peak voltages from the oscilloscope for the tuned case, it resulted as  -35.7dB. When manually changing the frequency to observe the difference for the ideal 40kHz frequency the waveform resulted having -35.6dB.

Am I right in saying there is a 14% difference in the intensity of power produced with the ultrasonic assembly being out of phase by 3.9dB, I understand decibel is a logarithmic scale however, cannot put into perspective the exact difference in intensity.

Comment: What are you trying to understand?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I understand what I am asking now. im trying to understand in terms of percentages; how much difference interms of power there is by 3.9dB by the frequency being out of Phase.